# Is there a standard for specifying the direction of a right angle wired connector?

Tags: connector, cables

When using connectors on wires (e.g. USB cables), there are four potential directions the wire can face relative to the connector:

[image: Four right-angle USB-A connectors with different orientations]

(image snipped from https://www.newnex.com/usb-right-angle-cables.php).

Is there a standard for referring to the directions of these connectors? "Up" and "Down" are fairly obvious, but "left" and "right" are ambiguous depending on if you are looking from the perspective of the cable or the connector.

I'm curious as writing specifications for these cables would be easier if there was a standard.

Comment: I'm not sure up and down are unambiguous as USB connectors can be mounted vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: Just add the appropriate picture to your specification to achieve ultimate disambiguity.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. All of them would be called "right angle".

Comment: Specify the connector you want to use then there isn't a choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are knows as right angle connectors, the orientation would be manufacturer specific.

Lcom defines the cables listed in the picture of OP above as follows:

Down angle, right angle,  Up angle , Left angle

[image]
Source: https://www.l-com.com/usb-right-angle-usb-cable-assemblies